# PHP write to a file and upload to screen

Tags: php

I'm Importing Data in my Database and I'd like to provide some error/feedback to the user in a text file, but I'm not sure how to approach it. My code is pretty long so I'll put a sample code to write in a file

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

In this case I would want "John Doe" twice in my file and upload to the screen so that the user can download it

Answer (score 1):

You can use php `readfile()` to send a file to the output buffer. You can look at the php docs for an example on how to do this. [Readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

A sample would look like this

```
if (file_exists($myfile)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($myfile).'"');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($myfile));
    readfile($myfile);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the Snippet below:

```
    <?php

    $fileName       = "data-log.txt";

    // IF THE FILE DOES NOT EXIST, WRITE TO IT AS YOU OPEN UP A STREAM,
    // OTHERWISE, JUST APPEND TO IT...
    if(!file_exists($fileName)){
        $fileMode   = "w";
    }else{
        $fileMode   = "a";
    }

    // OPEN THE FILE FOR WRITING OR APPENDING...
    $fileHandle     = fopen($fileName, $fileMode) or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt            = "John Doe\n";
    fwrite($fileHandle, $txt);

    $txt            = "Jane Doe\n";
    fwrite($fileHandle, $txt);
    fclose($fileHandle);


    // PUT THE FILE UP FOR DOWNLOAD:
    processDownload($fileName);

    function processDownload($fileName) {
        if($fileName){
            if(file_exists($fileName)){
                $size   = @filesize($fileName);
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
                readfile($fileName);
                exit;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
?>
```

Comment: For some reasons I keep getting `Unable to open file!` -_____-